# Team foundation service - set an administrator profile

Tags: tfs, admin

I am new to using Team foundation service and I couldn't find the answer on Google. I want to delete a project which I created. The reason being that I was playing around with Team foundation service to see how it works. But I want to tidy it up and delete projects not being used.

I tried using the developer command prompt for VS2012 using this command:

```
TfsDeleteProject /force /collection:https://COMPANYNAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection MYPROJECTNAME
```

And the developer command prompt for VS2012 response is this:

To use this command, you must be a member of either the Team Foundation Server Administrators group or a member of the Project Administrators group for the project you are deleting.

Can anyone provide some help with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be an Administrator to delete a project, either project administrator or server administrator. It is a safety feature built in TFS that prevents users deleting a project. If the project was created by mistake then you can ask your administrator to delete it. If you are the administrator, you can delete it from TSF administration console.